# Replace specific character MySQL search on utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Tags: mysql, unicode

I want to search my database for the character `İ` - "latin capital letter i with dot above (U+0130)" - and replace it with a regular `I` (U+0049).

For example, I want to transform "SİNG" to "SING".

The database collation is utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

I can find the characters using `COLLATE utf8mb4_bin`

```
SELECT *  FROM `benches` WHERE `inscription` LIKE '%İ%' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
```

But I can't replace it.

```
UPDATE `benches` SET inscription = REPLACE(inscription, 'İ', 'I') WHERE  INSTR(inscription, 'İ') > 0 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
```

I get the error

```
#1253 - COLLATION 'utf8mb4_bin' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
```

Which is weird because the database and column are definitely `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

So, what magic invocation do I need to search and replace a specific Unicode character from within a string?

Comment: Most likely the character set for your table is defined as latin1. Please share the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`  statement results

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE benches` gives "`inscription` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL"
`SHOW TABLE STATUS` gives `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` for all tables.

Comment: This might sound obvious, but is this command issued from a code file? Is the file where you wrote your code in UTF8 format or is it in ASCII/ANSI? It needs to be UTF8. Or maybe you are using Putty and this might be applicable?  http://thegreyblog.blogspot.com/2009/08/configuring-putty-to-use-utf-8.html?m=1.   Tell us more about your environment.

Comment: I'm using PHPmyAdmin.

Comment: Why are you using two different `WHERE` clauses? What happens in the second statement if you use `WHERE inscription LIKE '%İ%' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin` or in the first if you use `WHERE  INSTR(inscription, 'İ') > 0 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin` ?

Comment: I just wonder if the `COLLATE utf8mb4_bin` portion of your second statement is getting applied to the expression `INSTR(inscription, 'İ') > 0` (which should be just "true" or "false"). Why do you want a `COLLATE` clause on the UPDATE anyway?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`

Answer (score 0):

The quick fix might be

```
UPDATE `benches`
    SET inscription = REPLACE(inscription, _utf8mb4'İ' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin, 'I')
    WHERE  INSTR(inscription, _utf8mb4'İ' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin) > 0
```

A better fix might be to execute this after connecting:

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
```

If neither of these work, please provide a test case that includes creating and populating a table, plus the `UPDATE`.  It may take some experimentation to conjure up another potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success with a query like:

```
UPDATE `benches` 
SET inscription = REPLACE(inscription, 'İ', 'I') 
WHERE  inscription LIKE '%İ%' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```